# php DateTime add or sub hours alter other datetime

Tags: php, datetime, google-calendar-api

let's imagine that we have 2 events that has to be created at the same time.
Both have the same start date.
I have to add 1 hour to the first event and add 1 minute to the other.

Where the first event is first created, the second event got 1 hour more (because of the a hour add in the script)
Where the second event is first created, the first event got the 1 minute more because of the script.

Here how i add time to the date :

```
$event->create($date_start) { $date_start->modify('+1 hour'); }
```

There's not all the script, for confidential reasons.
Behind the code, the script create an event Google Calendar.

So, it's seems that add or sub days/hours etc... alter the other date... maybe i'm missing something ?

Comment: Odds are you have two variables pointing to the same object. What you really want to be using is `DateTimeImmutable()`.

Comment: `$date2 = clone $date1;` or use the immutable version as John has suggested.